# adding attribute to dynamic controls generated in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table created in javascript. On each row i am adding a checkbox. On checking the checkbox a warning message has to be displayed. how to add the oncheck attribute to a dynamic checkbox in javascript.

```
var tblRow = "<tr><td Style='display: none'>" + data.IxDetails
        "</td><td>" + data.Name +
             "</td><td>" + GroupTable +
              "</td><td>" + (data.AllowFileAttachment == true ? "Yes" :"No" )  +
        "</td><td>" + (data.SetToInActive == true ? "INACTIVE" : "ACTIVE" ) +
              "</td><td><input type = 'checkbox' id='" +
       data.Index + "' name='selectedData'  value='123' "+
        "</td><td><input type = 'checkbox' id='dl" +
       data.Index + "' name='selectedData'  value='123' >" +
        "</td></tr>";
        $('#DataTable> tbody:last').append(tblRow);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try me:

```
 $('table tr').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
         alert("I'm clicked!");
 });
```

[**SIMPLEST DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jSQdB/3/)

Comment: You dont have to use `find()` but place `'input:checkbox'` as a 2nd parameter on your `on()` instead.

Comment: SIMPLEST DEMO FIDDLE. nice. hehehe. alert("I'm clicked") vs alert('just clicked!');

Comment: @VondRitz but it will not work on dynamically added checkboxes. Read event delegation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ :)

Comment: and remove `tr` from `$('table tr')`.. =)

Comment: But how to differentiate between the two checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

Since the `checkbox` is added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler.

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#DataTable').on('click', ':checkbox', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
});
```

This will attach your event to any `checkbox` within the `#DataTable` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

[**A SIMPLE WORKING FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtRGB/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var tblRow = "<tr><td Style='display: none'>" + data.IxDetails
        "</td><td>" + data.Name +
             "</td><td>" + GroupTable +
              "</td><td>" + (data.AllowFileAttachment == true ? "Yes" :"No" )  +
        "</td><td>" + (data.SetToInActive == true ? "INACTIVE" : "ACTIVE" ) +
              "</td><td><input type = 'checkbox' onchange='yourfunction()' id='" +
       data.Index + "' name='selectedData'  value='123' "+
        "</td><td><input type = 'checkbox' onchange='yourfunction()' id='dl" +
       data.Index + "' name='selectedData'  value='123' >" +
        "</td></tr>";
        $('#DataTable> tbody:last').append(tblRow);
```

Answer (score 1):

for dynamically added controls better use

```
<input type = 'checkbox' id='dl" +
       data.Index + "' name='selectedData' href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dynaclick('id1')"  value='123' >
```

and javascript function is

```
function dynaclick(id){
alert('checkbox with'+id+' is clicked');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically generated content you could use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("form").on("change", function(event) {
  alert('Checkbox click!');
});
```